# Why don't my texts center with tkinter in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently coding a "chess randomizer" in python but I have a problem. When I open the new window, the texts and the buttons are not in the center of the window. Can someone help me please ?
Thank you very much.

Here is my code :

```
    new_window = Tk()
    new_window.geometry("400x300")
    new_window.minsize(400, 300)
    new_window.title("Déplacement aléatoire")
    new_window.config(background='#9999FF')

    text_frame = Frame(new_window, background='#9999FF', width=400, height=150)
    buttons_frame = Frame(new_window, background='#9999FF', width=400, height=150)
    button1_frame = Frame(buttons_frame, background='#9999FF', width=200, height=150)
    button2_frame = Frame(buttons_frame, background='#9999FF', width=200, height=150)


    text = Label(text_frame, text=f"Bougez la pièce en {switch_to_conventional(number)}, ({piece.name})", font=("Arial", 15), bg='#9999FF', fg='#000000')
    text.pack(expand='YES')
    text = Label(text_frame, text="La pièce peut-elle bouger ? ", font=("Arial", 10), bg='#9999FF', fg='#000000')
    text.pack(expand='YES')
    button1 = Button(button1_frame, text='Oui', font=("Arial", 10), bg='#9999FF', fg='#000000')
    button2 = Button(button2_frame, text='Non', font=("Arial", 10), bg='#9999FF', fg='#000000')
    button1.pack(expand='YES')
    button2.pack(expand='YES')

    text_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')
    buttons_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='news')
    button1_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
    button2_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)

    new_window.mainloop()
```

Thank you a lot !
Here si a screenshot : [My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BqBT.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should go with `.pack` geometry manager.

```
from tkinter import *
new_window = Tk()
new_window.geometry("400x300")
new_window.minsize(400, 300)
new_window.title("Déplacement aléatoire")
new_window.config(background='#9999FF')
text_frame = Frame(new_window, background='#9999FF', width=400, height=150)
buttons_frame = Frame(new_window, background='#9999FF', width=400, height=150)
button1_frame = Frame(buttons_frame, background='#9999FF', width=200, height=150)
button2_frame = Frame(buttons_frame, background='#9999FF', width=200, height=150)
text = Label(text_frame, text="Bougez la pièce en )", font=("Arial", 15), bg='#9999FF', fg='#000000')
text.pack()
text1 = Label(text_frame, text="La pièce peut-elle bouger ? ", font=("Arial", 10), bg='#9999FF', fg='#000000')
text1.pack()
button1 = Button(button1_frame, text='Oui', font=("Arial", 10), bg='#9999FF', fg='#000000')
button2 = Button(button1_frame, text='Non', font=("Arial", 10), bg='#9999FF', fg='#000000')
button1.pack(side="left")
button2.pack(side="left")
text_frame.pack(fill="both",expand=1)
buttons_frame.pack(fill="both",expand=1)
button1_frame.pack(side='top',anchor="center")
new_window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to center them horizontally, then change

```py
text_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')
buttons_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='news')
```

to

```
text_frame.pack()
buttons_frame.pack()
```

However if you want to center them vertically as well, change to:

```py
new_window.rowconfigure((0,1), weight=1, uniform=1)
new_window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

text_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='s')
buttons_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='n')
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ! It works. Can you give me a link to learn the sticky plz ? I don't find one and it's interesting

Comment: @YogS See official [document](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/grid.htm#M19).